# Validating an entity in EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

How to validate my entity? I want to check if the `url` property is unique. So I did this:
My `Post.php` entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
....
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Unique]
    private ?string $url = null;
....
```

This is obviously not enough because my entity is not validated on create/update. So I tried to add a group like:

```
....
#[Assert\GroupSequence(['post_validation'])]
class Post
....
```

And call the group in the `PostGroupController.php`:

```
public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular($this->translator->trans('post.post'))
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural($this->translator->trans('post.posts'))
            ->setSearchFields(['title'])
            ->setFormOptions(['validation_groups' => 'post_validation']);
    }
```

But this doesn't work either. By not working I mean that the record is saved/updated with not unique `url`. So what is wrong with this EasyAdmin validation or I am doing the things wrong ? P.S. I have the symfony validator installed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use the assert, please try this one:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', unique: true)]
private $url;
```